# azure-iot-hubにてmvn installコマンドを実行したときのエラーについて

Tags: java, azure, maven, oss

javaで作成されたOSS(azure-iot-hub)を、linux環境(CentOS)にダウンロードし、jarファイルを作成したいと思っております。

mvn installを実行した際に下記のエラーが出るのですが、原因は分かりますでしょうか？

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:3.0.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:jar:3.0.1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:pom:3.0.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: 名前またはサービスが不明です: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org: 名前またはサービスが不明です -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mavenのリモートリポジトリーに接続できていないみたいですね。

以下を試してみてください。

- そのLinuxマシンから http://repo.maven.apache.org にアクセスできるかどうか確認して、できない場合は、OSのネットワーク設定を見直す
- インターネットアクセスにプロキシーサーバーを経由している場合は、Mavenの`settings.xml`のプロキシー設定をチェックする（`<proxies>`タグ部分）

上記以外の場合は、`mvn`コマンド実行時にオプション`-e`とか`-X`を付加して、詳細なログを出力するようにしてみてください

Comment: 自己解決しました。プロキシの設定が上手くいっていなかったみたいです。ありがとうございました。

Comment: @aaaaaaaaaaw122 解決したら回答を[クローズ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)しておいて下さい

Comment: @KoheiTAMURA スタック・オーバーフローにおいて「クローズ」は「[改善待ち](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)」の意味で使われるので、解決した回答に対しての対応は「 **承認** 」という言葉を使った方が誤解が少ないです。

Comment: @cubick 確かにそうですね。次からそうコメントします。ご指摘ありがとうございます～。